# how to t.test for 2+groups data to multi columns?

Tags: r

I plan to do t.test for `q1,q2,q3` by group `A&B` in df

```
q1 q2 q3 group
1  0  1  A
0  1  0  B
1  1  1  C
0  1  0  B
```

If only 2groups, I can use `t.test(q1~group,df)
lapply(d[,-4], function(i) t.test(i ~ d$group))`,but how to do t.test between group `A & B` when I have 3 groups?

Comment: If looking to test equality of means across more than two groups, you could use the F test. This test is sensitive to departures from normality. A non-parametric analog is the quade test: `?quade.test`.

Comment: i only want to compare 2 groups `A&B`,the T test is best, but R's function has no option to my experiment.

Comment: In that case, restrict the data set in the first argument to only include groups A and B: `lapply(d[d$group %in% c("A", "B"),-4], function(i) t.test(i ~ d$group))`.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474672/looping-through-t-tests-for-data-frame-subsets-in-r/37479506#37479506